# Webserver hostname issue after Win10 April update

Tags: php, windows, apache, hostname

I have web server in my local network (Apache/2.4.10 + PHP 5.6.36 on Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 4.9.35-v7+ on Raspberry Pi) with hostname *webserver*. Then I'm also using a local webserver (*localhost*) on my workstation (Win 10 Home 64bit + Apache/2.4.25 + PHP 7.1.4).

After update to Win 10 "April update" (1803) I have this issue: when a PHP script on my *localhost* (i.e. workstation) tries read some file from *webserver* via file_get_contents()

```
$content=file_get_contents("http://webserver/file.php");
```

I get this error:

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
```

When I change hostname to IP address (`http://192.168.1.100/file.php`) then it works. Also there is no problem when I put `http://webserver/file.php` directly in my broswer (on workstation). The problem is only when a script from *localhost* (workstation) is trying to reach address on *webserver* with hostname in address.

Before Win 10 April update everything  worked fine, so where can be a problem? I have installed all Windows updates but it didn't help...

Comment: Hi, did you try to deactivate your firewall and anti-virus?

Comment: @night-gold : Yes, but still not working...

Comment: Did you check that your HOSTS file is still as it was. Maybe the Windows Update has reset the HOSTS file to the default

Comment: @RiggsFolly You are right! Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your HOSTS file in `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\HOSTS`

Some Windows updates replace this file with a default, which would explain why you can no longer access the server as there will be no reference to it in the HOSTS file.